# LowLatencyAudio broken in 3.4.0?

Tags: node.js, cordova, include, npm

This plugin seems to be broken in 3.4.0
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-lowlatencyaudio

Any ideas what changed between 3.3.0 and 3.4.0 that could have caused this?

It seems like the object `LowLatencyAudio` doesn't exist in the global scope.

[image]

Even though I can see from Chrome DevTools inspect (while testing on mobile) that the `LowLatencyAudio.js` has been included in the `<head>` tag.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it window.**plugins**.LowLatencyAudio instead of window.LowLatencyAudio?

Doesn't really seem related to new cordova version.

Comment: Well Media is in the global scope and that's an official plugin so why wouldn't the unofficial ones be accessed in the same way.

Comment: Also in 3.3.0 it was window.LowLatencyAudio

Comment: aparently, 6 months ago it was already plugins.lowlatencyaudio. When you build your own  plugin you choose whatever namespace you want. Most of official plugins like File or Media are based on HTML5 APIs and so use the same namespace. Some plugin builders choose to put their plugins in the plugins namespace to minimise riscs of conflicts with other scripts. When you want to use a plugin, start by read the readme.md or doculentation. Or if none look at the `clobbers` tag in plugin.xml For lowlatencyaudio, you will find doc and samples in the doc folder of the repo.